# Latest ada-mode (5.1.9) does not indent on Emacs for OS X (24.5.1)

Tags: emacs, ada

I recently upgraded from the ada-mode built-in to Emacs for the updated elpa version (5.1.9) due to issues with compiling from within ada-mode with the earlier version (4.0.0).

In the updated package it is impossible to indent, with `TAB` performing no operation at all except to move all text on all lines to the leftmost column, regardless of whether it should be indented or not. No other type of indenting (`ada-indent-current`, `ada-indent-region`, or `ada-indent-newline-indent`) work either and neither does automatic indentation via `RET`.

There is no mention in `*Messages*` that there is any problem, and the built-in version has no trouble with the indentation.

I'm quite new to Emacs, but I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now with no solution in sight.

My `init.el` is below in case I've simply done something strange in my noviceness:

```
(package-initialize)
;; (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)

(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))


(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp")

(global-linum-mode t) ;; Show line numbers

(autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode" "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.text\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.markdown\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md\\'" . markdown-mode))

(when (eq system-type 'darwin) ;; mac specific settings
  (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta))

(setq exec-path-from-shell-check-startup nil)
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))

(ac-config-default)
```

Comment: Works for me. What is TAB bound to? [C-h k TAB] Should be `indent-for-tab-command`, and C-h v indent-line-function should say `wisi-indent-line`.

Comment: @SimonWright Yes, these are all the same. I tried disabling the `auto-complete` minor mode, but this didn't help anything either. Upon further investigation, if I execute `wisi-indent-line` and then check the variable `wisi-indent-failed` it always seems to be `t`, maybe indicating a parsing error? My Lisp isn't that great so I couldn't say for sure, but it looks like there is a problem with the `wisi` installation somehow...

Comment: Did you update the wisi package? should be 1.1.2 (M-x package-list-packages)

Comment: You say "maybe indicating a parsing error”, and in fact the behaviour you’re seeing is what the new ada-mode does if (it thinks that) the Ada code is syntactically incorrect. Try C-c C-f (menu Ada > Misc > Show last parse error), which tries to put point on the location of the error and gives you a minibuffer-full of failed alternatives. Are you aware of the [ada-mode mailing list](http://host114.hostmonster.com/mailman/listinfo/emacs-ada-mode_stephe-leake.org)?

Comment: And sometimes the parser gets confused: if C-c C-f says the parse is OK, try menu Ada > Misc > Reset parser (M-x ada-reset-parser) and then menu Ada > Edit > Indent lines in file.